# Using and controlling Spring transactions within Struts 2 actions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, struts2

I have been working for a while on a project with the following components:

- Struts2.1.8.1,
- Spring 3.0.3
- JPA 2.0,
- Hibernate 3

I am using Spring's EntityManager magic... But I'm having problems dealing with transactions inside my actions. For instance, I am setting values on my persisted object in several methods within my class, and I want to be able to `rollback` if the `validate` method finds a validation error, or `commit` these changes otherwise. I have already spent quite a long time reading half of the internet for a comprehensive explanation. Unfortunately, no complete examples exist (at least similar to my stack).

I have stumbled with this thread on a mailing list: [@Transactional Spring Annotation in a Struts2 Action does not work](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/struts-user/200905.mbox/%3C4A038DAE.6060200@it-neering.net%3E). The message I'm linking at seems to have a pretty simple and straightforward solution, using a `TransactionInterceptor` will do the trick it seems... The problem is that I'm not finding useful information regarding this interceptor.

Anyone here has experience with this technology and can spare a tip and a link or two on how to use Spring transactions inside Struts2 actions?

Thanks!

**- Edit 1 -**

I have set up a test project if you are interested, just [download the file](http://pynfo.com/misc/PersistencyTest.zip) and try it out (or inspect it). Thanks!

Comment: I am capable with struts2 however I've been having some integration issues as well, I will help with research on this if if you could provide a skeleton application (working configuration files and pom.xml).

Comment: Hi Quaternion, I could provide you with a copy of a test project that mimics the configuration of our big project. But we warned, it is a checkout of our repository, no pom, just a big good old zip file). Just... let me pack it up and upload it....

Comment: Hi Quaternion, I'm very sorry that I couldn't post the file before, but It's finally up. If you have any time to peek around it, I'n going to be extremely grateful. By the way, I followed Steven Benitez's suggestion on his answer below, but I had no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, controllers/actions/backing beans/etc don't handle transactions. Actions are the web-part of your back-end code - they should only be concerned with gathering request data, and sending response data. The logic itself (including database access) should be done in another layer. E.g. a service layer. So you create another bean, inject it in the action, and make it do the work - `userService.register(user)`. Then configuring transactions on a service layer should be trivial since it is both in the spring documentation and in countless examples:

`<tx:annotation-driven />` and `@Transactional` (btw, make sure you have the `<tx:..>` now, it might be causing the issue. Even if it works, this does not invalidate my suggestion about the service layer)

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with that... the problem is that I have several different classes... 15 or so... Which in turn have associations with other classes... I really do not want to repeat a lot of code, and I feel that using the service pattern will just add lots of repeated (and possibly buggy) code... Is this the only way? I really want to have the set/validate combo inside a transaction, that's all I need... any ideas? :D

Comment: You mean to have the set method directly place the data into the database and if validate() fails roll it back?  If this is the case it should be avoided.

Comment: one-layer applications are sometimes fine if they are small and likely to remain small. However I can't give you more info before I see your configuration and some code.

Comment: Just to understand how this multiple layer architecture works... I will need one action for each class, which in turn then will invoke a specific method in my service(s) (say... update House). This method inside my service WILL be wrapped inside a transaction, so with the proper configuration it will rollback on errors. That's the right/normal way to do it? It just sounds insane having to repeat this x15 times to cover each one of my classes... :(

Comment: Not necessarily. But as I said - I can't be more specific without seeing any code.

Comment: My humble vote goes for your answer, after all, I just needed a good dose of examples, thanks Bozho! I added a little more detail on my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like answering my own question, but since I **solved** this ages ago... I thought I should share the knowledge (or lack of... in this case).

The book I was using to learn about Struts 2 and Spring-JPA-Hibernate, adds the `@Transactional` annotation right before the declaration of the service class. This is terribly wrong, for all methods (including those that only retrieve stuff from the database) are inside a committable transaction. Long story short everything got committed event if exceptions occurred.

The solution, as Bozho so wisely pointed out, was to look at examples. That is, set your transtactional methods carefully, in my case I set up transactions for the methods that had to write back to the database and everything started to work just fine.

Thanks to Steven and Quaternion too for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, here's what I understand about your problem.

You want to wrap your action invocation in a transaction. If the validate method records validation errors, you want to roll the transaction back. Presumably, you also want to rollback in case of an error.

**Solution**

Create an interceptor that will:

- Start a transaction
- Invoke the action inside of a try/catch block
- Rollback the transaction if there is an exception or if there are any validation errors on the action (this can be detected using action.hasErrors)
- Commit the transaction

You will probably want this interceptor defined pretty early in the stack. I don't know of any pre-built interceptors for this (although there may be some), but it should be fairly easy to assemble.

**Update**

I don't use Spring, so I can't say how the JPA transaction support works there, but you can handle transactions for your EntityManager like:

```
try {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    // do your thing
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    throw new PersistenceException(e);
}
```

This is just a crude example, but it should illustrate the point.

Comment: Hi Steven, that's one great idea... the problem is that I do not know how to start a transaction when using Spring's EntityManager. Once I find a way to do that, this solution you're proposing will work like a charm. Any ideas on how to get an EntityManager's transactions?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Steven, I finally ventured into the world of Interceptors (they're pretty cool I must say). I created an interceptor which is injected by Spring with my service class (the class that has the EntityManager) and wrapped the invocation of my actions in a code block like you suggested here. Unfortunately I got a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead` exception.

Comment: I don't use Spring, so I can't comment on that error message other than to say it is Spring-specific. You may want to Google the error message to see if there is a way to have Spring let you manage your own transaction or perhaps revise your question here and see if you get any further answers. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I figured... Thanks for the tips though Steven! I'll keep searching.